# jQuery: previous children with class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the height of all the previous children inside of a `ul` element, that has the same class name off the "active" element.

HTML example:

```
<ul class="board-album">
    <li class="album-item item-left"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-right"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-left"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-right"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-left"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-right"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-left"></li>
    <li class="album-item item-right"></li>
</ul>
```

So I need to get the height off previous children with class 'item-left' and then the height off 'item-right'.

jQuery example:

```
$('.item-left').each( function(){
    $(this).prevAll().outerHeight();
});
```

I have also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm3o7w9z/) that shows something similar to my problem, but the thing is that it will be with images inside the `li` elements, so the height will be different.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Example: 
The last `item-left` should only get the combined height of each previous children with the same class name and the same for `item-right`

Comment: What's your problem/question?

Comment: The problem is that it don't work getting the previous children with the same class name. All I need is a solution on getting the previous children's height with the same class name, either 'item-left' or 'item-right'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to know height of previous elements in one of the columns, right? I did it on click not sure if this is what you wanted. You can paste it in your fiddle and click one of the items.

Keep in mind it will still count those absolutely positioned elements.

```
    $('.album-item').click(function(){
        selector = '.'+this.className.match(/item-[A-z]*/)[0]
        height = 0
        $(this).prevAll(selector).each(function(){
            height+=$(this).outerHeight()
            }
        )
        alert(height)
      }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed! I'm not going to use a click function on this, but I have removed the complete click function so it goes on its own. Again, Thanks! :)